# JQuery .submit does't work (weird issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap model inside that model there's a form to submit some images using Ajax.

The problem is  when ever I use this simple JQuery code

the page refresh and no alert or submission occurs.

Whenever  I remove   `<td>`  or `$data.='`  from model button
the jquery code works, but I can't remove them since all html codes in the program are assigned to variable like" $data.=' "

JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Doc_image_upload").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        alert('test');
    });   
});
```

The model button

```
$data.='<td>
            <button class="unassigned remove'.$shipment['id'].'" 
                    id="shipmentid" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="        
                    .bd-example-modal-lg2'.$shipment['id'].'"
                    value1="'.$shipment['id'].'">More</button> 
        </td></tr></form>';   ?>
```

form

```
<div class="collapse" id="uploadimage<?php echo $shipment['id']; ?>">
    <div class="well well2">
        <form  class="Doc_image_upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" value1="<?php echo $shipment['id']; ?>">
            <label>Upload Document:</label><br/>
            <input type="file" name="doc_image" > <br/>
            <select name="doctype" required>
                <option value="">Select Type</option>
                <?php echo Doc_type() ?></select></label> <br/>
            <label>Document Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="docnumber" placeholder="Enter Document number " pattern='[0-9]{10}' title="Please enter 10 digits" required>  <br/>
            <label>Document Expire Date:</label><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="uploadDoc" value1="<?php echo $shipment['id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $customer_id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="shipmentid" value="<?php echo  $shipment['id']; ?>">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix it ?

/////--------------------------------------------/////////////
Add more code

```
  <form  method="post" id="employee_form">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-small-12">
                    <div style="    margin-bottom: 100px;" class="tbl-content">
                        <div  class="tbl-header">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Select</th>
                                    <th>Airwaybill</th>
                                    <th>USD Amt</th>
                                    <th>Wt</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Consignee</th>
                                    <th>Orig</th>
                                    <th>Dest</th>
                                    <th>Prod Cd</th>


                                    <th>Status</th>

                                    <th>more</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>


                        <div class="assign_to">
                         <label>Assign to</label>
                          <select name="Employee" class="Employee" >
                                <option value="0">Select User</option>
                              <?php echo load_Employee() ; ?>
                           </select>
                             <input type="submit" id="assign" class="unassigned"  value="Assign">
                        </div>

                               <?php
                        $data .='       
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="results_unassigned" id="check">

                        <tbody>

                        '; while($shipment = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_customer_rule,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $data .='          <tr>

                            <td>
                               <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="shipment_id[]" value="'.$shipment['id'].'">
                            </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['awbno'].'

                          </td>                             

                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['shipvalue'].'
                          </td>
                          <td >
                            '.$shipment['weight'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['contentdesc'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['consigneename'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['origin'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['destination'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              '.$shipment['prodcontentcd'].'
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            '.$shipment['status'].'
                          </td>';


         $data.='<td>
            <button class="unassigned remove'.$shipment['id'].'" 
                    id="shipmentid" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="        
                    .bd-example-modal-lg2'.$shipment['id'].'"
                    value1="'.$shipment['id'].'">More</button> 
        </td></tr></form>';   ?>
```

addition

This issue doesn't  occur if I display the page using jquery

```
$('whatevet').html(data);
```

Comment: What's the generated output of the modal button? (note - "modal", not "model")

Comment: the modal used to show more options.  The Jquery code works after I remove  <td>  or  $data =''   that surrounded the modal button

Comment: Its not clear from the code you have given, but it looks like you might be nesting forms, one on the main html and one in the model dialog, and that is why commenting out $data makes it work because you removed the nested closing tag. If you check the generated html, you should be able to verify this.

Comment: where do you have this  </td></tr></form>? It is not well formed

Comment: I will update the question and insert more codes

Comment: Have you tried with event delegation? `$("body").on("submit", ".Doc_image_upload", function(e) { ... });`

Comment: Please show your final compiled HTML, without any PHP statements (`<?php`) still in it.

Comment: I  found cause of the issue, it's because of the form  at bottom, since it was in the loop so its repeated many time, which makes overlap  between form tags.  I spent 10 hours to figure this out. Thank   you " philreed " you saved me ^^

Comment: But I don't know why it works when I remove td tags. but at least it works